# (VB.NET) Issues Adding or Extracting .cab Files as Resource Files

Tags: vb.net, zip, cab

I am working with VB.NET and cannot seem to add .cab files to my resources properly? Or maybe extraction is my issue?

I can add single files fine such as .bat and .txt. I go through the same process and even see the Cab files in resources with the other files. I set them up as Content and Copy Always like the others. But when I extract all the resource files with my standalone EXE, the Cab files output as just empty file. Any other single resource file extracts fine.

If it is my extraction process, my code is below:

```
    Private Sub CreateFile(ByVal Resource As Object, ByVal FullPath As String)
        Dim TheFile As StreamWriter
        Try
            TheFile = New StreamWriter(FullPath)
            TheFile.Write(Resource)
            TheFile.Close()
        Catch
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I was under the impression .cab files were *actual* files unless they are seen as compressed folders by windows? I originally had a .ZIP with sub folders that I successfully converted to a .CAB so my EXE can deploy it with the folder/directory structure intact. On my coding PC I can manually expand the CAB and the file structure is intact. There are about 4-5 files per sub-folder and 3 sub-folders with a readme.txt at the main folder level.

Maybe .cab is not the best way to go? Any other ways to get a .zip of folders and files into a resource in VB.NET if .CAB is not the way? Or maybe I am missing a module or something else that could help?

Comment: `StreamWriters` are for writing text. CAB files are not text. What exactly do you get back when you extract the resource? I would guess a `Byte` array. In that case, call `File.WriteAllBytes` to write the data to a file.

Comment: You should turn `Option Strict On` in both this project and in VS for future projects. That will force you to pay closer attention to data types. That code would not compile with `Option Strict On`.

Comment: I do have `Option Strict ON` set and I do not get any errors. I will try `File.WriteAllBytes` and see if that was my issue. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I write a subroutine to write an embedded binary resource to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72494432/how-can-i-write-a-subroutine-to-write-an-embedded-binary-resource-to-a-file)

Comment: I was thinking that there was no Write method that took an Object argument but I was wrong about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite easy actually, thanks to John's comment above regarding `File.WriteAllBytes`

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(FilePathWithFileName, _
     My.Resources.YourResourceName, False)
```

Which allowed me to create the .CAB files perfectly.

In case anyone is having a similar issue, and needs the code to then expand a CAB, that was easy too:

```
Dim ExtractCAB As New ProcessStartInfo("Expand", _
     """FilePathWithFileName"" -F:* ""ExtractFilePath""") _
     With {.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden, .Verb = "runas"}

Process.Start(ExtractCAB)
```